# Passing value with xargs to generate dynamic output filename

Tags: linux, grep, xargs, filter

I have some files in a folder. By running the following command I can create a list with the filtered filenames ( test1, test2,test3) and pass it using xargs to a grep filtering command **filter** file in the command contains a few values to be filtered out.

```
ls -Art1 | grep test | xargs -L1 grep -vf filter > ouput
```

However when run this command output file contain the filtered result of test1, test2 and test3. All in one.

I would like to have separate file for each test1 > test1_output, test2 >test2_output,...
so taking the xargs value and just add an extra string to it "_output" to generate an output filename

Comment: It's not recommendable [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: The link. was useful, however in my case not really relevant. I am well aware of the "space in the name" issue and I always avoid it. These scripts are for personal use only so no big risk of faulty output. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome! And that's correct. While you don't have any problems with special filenames you can use `ls`without any problem although it's useful to know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to pipe the output of `ls` to search for a name match. Just use a shell glob. This also allows you to define an output file for each filter attempt

```
for file in *test*
do
    [ -f "./$file" ] && grep -vf filter "./$file" >"${file}_output"
done
```

Technically this is potentially a slightly different set of file matches to your `ls -A` as your code considers dot files whereas mine does not. Fixable if relevant.

In [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721813/passing-value-with-xargs-to-generate-dynamic-output-filename/721821?noredirect=1#comment1368620_721821) you mention you are performing two actions on each file. If I have understood you correctly, then for such a situation you can modify the code like this:

```
for file in *test*
do
    if [ -f "./$file" ]
    then
        grep -f filter "./$file" >"${file}_delta"
        grep -vf filter "./$file" >"${file}_output"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It is working as expected! Thanks!

Comment: I played a bit more with the solution and actually love it even more. I added additional command  to the script so now not only generates the output but also creates a delta between them. The "_delta" output is actually the same as executing the same line without the grep exclusion ("v") option.

Comment: @peti27 I've given you an option to address the `_delta` you mention